# How to do Flyway migrations eager in Play Framework

Tags: scala, playframework, flyway

I am using [flyway-play](https://github.com/flyway/flyway-play). What I want to do is to run the migration eagerly before other Components need the database.

I tried to inject the `FlywayPlayComponents` into my Setup, like:

```
@Singleton
class AppSetup @Inject()(val environment: Environment,
                            val webCommands: WebCommands,
                            val configuration: Configuration,
                       )
  extends FlywayPlayComponents {

  flywayPlayInitializer
  ...
```

But `AppSetup` is still runs first and the *Flyway migration* is runs with the first request.

Is there a way to do this or do I miss something?